# How to add multiple strings from tds?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add multiple strings that are dollar amounts. I am getting NaN for the conversion from my `parseFloat`, but I remove the dollar sign and any commas. Any suggestions?

I've tried simply adding them without the `parseFloat`, but I just get a concatenated string.

```
function calculateTotalCost()
{
    var amt;
    var subTotal;

    for(i=1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        amt = document.getElementById("cphMain_gridPC").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
        var amtNum = amt.replace('$', '');
        var amtF = amtNum.replace(',', '');
        if(isNaN(amtF))
        {
            subTotal += 0.00;
        }
        else
        {
            subTotal += parseFloat(amtF);
            alert(subTotal);
        }
    }
    alert(subTotal);
}
```

I expect to get the subTotal or the each tds value added together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the replace method like that only replaces the **first** instance of that pattern in a string. What's likely happening is that a number like '3,000,000' is getting changed to '3000,000', which is why you're still getting isNaN(amtF) === true.

Try this:

```
var amtF = amtNum.replace(/,/g, '');
```

The slashes instead of quotations indicate that you're searching for a regex pattern, which additionally allows you to use the *g* flag. This stands for *global* and means that all instances of that pattern will be replaced.

**EDIT:**
 The issue is likely that you forgot to initialize subtotal as zero. Change this:

```
var subTotal;
```

to this:

```
var subTotal = 0;
```

Comment: I get that, but I don't have any numbers that large when I tested. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `amt` is equal to before the replaces?

Comment: Yeah, usually `$500.00` or `$3,000.00`

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. You forgot to set an initial value for subtotal, so rather than adding `amtF` to 0 initially, it tries to add it to `undefined`, which results in NaN. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, got it! Great! That fixed it @Jon Warren Thanks a bunch!